# ¿Cómo agregar referencias en Visual Studio?

Tags: vba, vb

Estoy intentando agregar las mismas referencias que utilicé en VBA (con Excel) para armar mi proyecto en Visual Studio 2017, pero no puedo añadir las referencias para interactuar con la app en cuestión (Reflection for regis graphic)

¿Existe algún otro método?

Con el Excel todo me funciona bien.-

[image: A]

En Excel sí me funciona.

[image: A]

Comment: ¿Que tipo de proyecto es?

Comment: VB - aplicación de forms

Comment: Visual Basic (.NET) no es lo mismo que VBA (Visual Basic for Applications). No puedes utilizar las librerias de un lenguaje en otro.

Comment: Osea que no puedo interactuar con Reflection desde VB?

Comment: Tal vez sea posible usando COM Interop. Disculpa está fuera de mis conocimientos

Comment: ALGUIEN SABE COMO ?